# DAT or AKK after "glauben"?

Tags: preposition

I found these two sentences:
Ich glaube deinem Wort.
Der Hund glaubt kein Wort.
Why does "glauben: take DAT in the first sentence and DAT in the second?

Comment: The verb *glauben* may take both an accusative and a dative object. The accusative object is the thing you believe to be true, and the dative object is whom you trust on that.
E.g.: *Ich glaube dir den Schwindel nicht.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The verb *glauben* taking the dative case has a slightly different meaning than that taking accusative. Namely, the former  means that one believes that something is true, gives somebody credit. Whom one gives credit is in dative while the object (Wort) one believes is a noun in accusative.

A further combination (an + A) rather evokes faith (*An Gott glauben; ich glaube an dich, usw.*).